# How can I add CSS classes to custom Wordpress meta boxes?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, meta-boxes

I am trying to add CSS classes to Wordpress meta boxes. I want the process to be reusable. This is what I was thinking:

Add Meta Box

```
add_meta_box('my_meta_box', 'My Meta Box', [$metaBoxesClass, 'display_meta_box'], 'my_post_type', 'normal', 'low', [
    'slug' => 'my_meta_box',
    'classes' => ['my-class']
]);
```

Display Meta Box (in `$metaBoxesClass` class)

```
public function display_meta_box($post = null, $o = []) {

    // add filter with anonymous callback, default priority and 2 arguments
    add_filter('postbox_classes_'.$post->post_type.'_'.$o["slug"], function($classes = [], $classesNew = []) {

            foreach($classesNew as $class) {

                array_push($classes, $class);
            }

            return $classes;

        }, 10, 2);

    // apply new filter with 2 arguments
    apply_filters('postbox_classes_'.$post->post_type.'_'.$o["slug"], [], $o['classes']);
}
```

I don't seem to get any errors doing this, but the class `my-class` isn't applied to my `my_meta_box` meta box. Can I not add a filter inside the `display_meta_box` callback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$o["args"]["slug"]` and `$o["args"]["classes"]` instead `$o["slug"]` and `$o["classes"]`.